# gulp-mocha how to pass the compilers flag?

Tags: javascript, gulp, mocha.js

I'm trying to use the [gulp-mocha module](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-mocha) but can't figure out a good way to pass over the compilers flag.  Is there a way to include this in my gulp task?  Maybe in a separate pipe somehow?

Example if running mocha from command line (works fine)
`mocha --compilers .:my_compiler.js test/**/*.js`

Example if using gulp-mocha (but where can I specify a compiler)?

```
gulp.task('test', function () {
    gulp.src(["test/**/*.js"], {
        read: false
    })
        .pipe(mocha({
            reporter: 'spec'
        }))
        .pipe(exit());
});
```

I don't see a compilers option under the gulp-mocha plugin, so I'm thinking I need to somehow add the compilers by appending the text through a pipe somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just noticed the docs at the bottom state -

> For CoffeeScript support, add require('coffee-script') with CoffeeScript 1.6- or require('coffee-script/register') with CoffeeScript 1.7+.

I added a require statement for my own compiler at the top of my gulp file `require('./my_compiler');` and this seemed to work.

Answer (score 16):

```
var mocha = require('gulp-mocha');
var babel = require('babel/register');

gulp.task('mocha', function() {
    return gulp.src(['test/**/*.js'])
        .pipe(mocha({
            compilers: {
                js: babel
            }
        }));
});
```

Comment: Please improve your answer. Explain how you solve this issue and what the user did wrong.

Comment: Hi @lin, gulp-mocha just wrap mocha, and we could pass the compilers as params.
We use babel to transform es6 to es5 as compiler in the gulp task.

Comment: regardless of the answer's clarity, it did fix my problem getting babel to compile my mocha tests. Thank you Juan!

Comment: `require(babel/register)` in the gulp file is not a clean solution because it loads the babel hook which from the documentation `will pollute the global scope and introduce conflicts` cf https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/require/. If you use this solution, it should be done only for test (but can still cause issue ...)

Comment: If you are using babel 6, the new way is `requre('babel-core/register')`. Be careful as `require('babel/register')` will no longer work. More:
https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/1359

Answer (score 9):

The top answer relies on using the require hook. This will only work in the current process, and not if you run Mocha tests in a separate process, as with `gulp-spawn-mocha`.

This is how you pass compilers into the mocha module:

```
    return mocha({
        compilers: [
            'js:babel-core/register',
        ]
    });
```

Mocha will loop through the elements of the `compilers` property and split on `:`. It will treat the string before it as the extensions to follow, and will inject everything after it into a `require()` statement.

Answer (score 8):

Use `require('babel-core/register');` at the start of the gulpfile

Answer (score 1):

For anyone trying it now

```
gulp.task('test-mocha', function() {
    return gulp.src(['tests/acceptance/*.js'], {read: false})
        .pipe(
            mocha({
                compilers: 'js:babel-core/register',
                reporter: 'landing'
            })
        )
        .on('error', gutil.log);
});
```

and on top of the gulp file (gulpfile.js)

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var gutil = require('gulp-util');
var mocha = require('gulp-mocha');
var babel = require('babel-register');
```

run your test and it should work

```
gulp test-mocha
```

Answer (score 0):

Justin Maat, you don't need to modify your `gulpfile.js`. You just need to use `--require` when using `gulp` from `CLI`:

```
### before
gulp test

### after
gulp --require babel/register test
```

Do you notice the difference? And to save you a few keystrokes, add this to your `.bashrc` or `.zshrc`:

```
alias gulp='gulp --require babel/register'
```

and next time, you can use `gulp` as normal

```
gulp test
```