# Mocha not loading .jsx files

Tags: meteor, mocha.js, reactjs, jsx

I am currently working on a Meteor & React project and I'd like to start TDDing. So far I have developed some tests using mocha and everything was fine. However, when I have started to test React components using Enzyme and I try to import a React component with a .jsx extension, it just can't load it. This is the error I get:

```
W20160826-14:06:00.087(2)? (STDERR) Error: Cannot find module '../client/ui/component/internship/student-item.jsx'
W20160826-14:06:00.087(2)? (STDERR)     at require (packages/modules-runtime/.npm/package/node_modules/install/install.js:85:1)
W20160826-14:06:00.087(2)? (STDERR)     at meteorInstall.test.internship.test.js (test/internship.test.js:3:1)
W20160826-14:06:00.088(2)? (STDERR)     at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime/.npm/package/node_modules/install/install.js:153:1)
W20160826-14:06:00.088(2)? (STDERR)     at require (packages/modules-runtime/.npm/package/node_modules/install/install.js:82:1)
W20160826-14:06:00.088(2)? (STDERR)     at /tmp/pablo/meteor-test-run6h5h3p/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/app/app.js:345:1
W20160826-14:06:00.089(2)? (STDERR)     at /tmp/pablo/meteor-test-run6h5h3p/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:292:10
W20160826-14:06:00.089(2)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20160826-14:06:00.090(2)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (/home/pablo/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.1_1.1vyh0jb++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
W20160826-14:06:00.090(2)? (STDERR)     at /tmp/pablo/meteor-test-run6h5h3p/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:128:5
```

I had a look at this: [Mocha will not recognise JSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35304797/mocha-will-not-recognise-jsx) but didn't solve my problem.

The packages I have installed are :

1. meteor add practicalmeteor:mocha
2. npm i --save-dev react-addons-test-utils
3. npm i --save-dev react-dom

After that I have tried installing some other packages with no luck:

- npm install --save-dev enzyme mocha chai chai-enzyme chai-jsx jsdom
  babel babel-core
- npm install --save-dev babel-preset-es2015 babel-preset-react babel-preset-stage-0

My test looks like this:

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { mount, shallow } from 'enzyme';
import StudentInternshipItem from '../client/ui/component/internship/student-item.jsx';

if (Meteor.isClient) {

  describe('<StudentInternshipItem />', () => {
    it("contains spec with an expectation", function() {
      // this is empty cause I just want to check that the component is loaded before actually testing anything.
    });
  });

}
```

Does anybody know what is going on? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not trying to teach you to suck eggs, but does that file actually exist?

Comment: Does it work if you rename the jsx file to js?

Comment: No, it doesn't. It's something related with the path. I have double checked 15 times and it's well traced. However, I have copied the .jsx file into the test folder so the import is from the same folder (./fileName.jsx) and it finds it. Any ideas why this is happening?