# Mocha/ Enzyme doesn't Recognise jsx

Tags: reactjs, mocha.js, jsx, babeljs, enzyme

My goal is to test reactjs code written with jsx with mocha as test runner, enzyme and chai. Currently I'm getting an `unexpectet token` error.
I already try the solution inside [mocha-will-not-recognise-jsx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35304797/mocha-will-not-recognise-jsx) but it didn't solves my error.

### Package.json

```
{
    "scripts": {
        "test": "mocha --recursive application/**/*.spec.js* --compilers js:babel-register",
    },
    [
    ...
    ],
    "dependencies": {
        "react": "^15.6.1",
        "react-dom": "^15.6.1"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
        "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
        "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.0",
        "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
        "babel-register": "^6.26.0",
        "chai": "^4.1.2",
        "enzyme": "^2.9.1",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
        "mocha": "^3.5.0",
        "standard": "^10.0.3",
        "webpack": "^3.5.5",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^2.7.1"
    }
}
```

### Webpack modules

```
module: {
    loaders: [{
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
            presets: ['react', 'env']
        }
    }]
}
```

### Error Message

```
D:\Development\game-of-life\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\index.js:59
0
    throw err;
    ^

SyntaxError: D:/Development/game-of-life/application/src/components/app/App.spec.jsx: U
nexpected token (8:28)
   6 | describe('App', () => {
   7 |   it('renders "<div>Application is running</div>"', () => {
>  8 |     const wrapper = shallow(<App />)
     |                             ^
   9 |     expect(wrapper.contains(<div>Application is running</div>)).to.be.eql(true)
  10 |   })
  11 | })
```

Did I forgot to install a package or does a newer version of a package works different to an older version of the package because I already realized with equal dependencies a react-enzyme project.

Comment: Could you please show me your test file?

Comment: mocha is not very good at reading jsx code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found two posible ways to solve the problem

#### .babelrc

Adding a `.babelrc` with the configureation `presets: ['react', 'env']`.

#### webpack

Adding a configuration (`babelrc: false`) to avoid `.babelrc` and to use the webpack configuration